# How to create an inner join with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. association

   - id
   - title
2. users

   - id
   - name
3. association_users

   - id
   - id_users
   - id_associations

I want to do on SQL this query :

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, u.id, u.name
      FROM association AS a
      INNER JOIN association_user AS au
      ON au.association_id = a.id
      INNER JOIN user AS u
      ON u.id = au.user_id
      WHERE au.user_id = ID
```

For the moment, I have this :

```
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->join('association.users', 'u')
                    ->addSelect('a')
                    ->join('user.id', 'u.id')
                    ->addSelect('u')
                    ->where("au.user_id = :id")
                    ->setParameter('id', $userid)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult()
    ;
```

But it's not working :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near '.users u INNER': Error: Identification Variable association used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

What's wrong with my querybuilder ?

**working code**

I have change the query to :

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')                              
                            ->innerJoin('a.users','u')
                            ->where('u.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $this->getUser()->getId());             
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entities are mapped correctly, then querybuilder will automatically join on the columns specified in your mapping and you do not need to specify them here again:

```
$qb->select("a,u")
        ->from('MyBundle\Association','a')
        ->innerJoin('a.users','u')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id',$userid);
```

Comment: I have update the code with the working code. Thanks for your help